# Strange Issue with Syntax Highlighter on Google Blogger

Tags: blogger, syntaxhighlighter

I have encountered a strange issue with Syntax Highlighter on Google Blogger.

I added Syntax Highlighter to my blog step by step,but it didn't worked for me, i reassured everything in the EDIT HTML of my blog.

Still the problem persisted.

Later i created a Test Blog to check whether the same method works or not & found out that Syntax Highlighter works with the Test Blog.

I know that syntax highlighter doesn't work with Dynamic View, but here both my Blogs have the Same Template.
The only Difference in both blogs is the Name and Address.Other than this both my blogs use Same Template.

- Please Check

Here's My [Main Blog](https://programmerrhub.blogspot.in/2017/03/test-program.html)

& Here's The [Test Blog](http://ranaom123.blogspot.in/2017/03/hello-word.html)

So what could be the issue..?

Comment: The syntax highlighting library seems to be missing in your main blog

Comment: No i rechecked it....syntax highlighting library is present in both the blogs...

Comment: I checked the main's blog source, the syntax highlighting library is not present. Maybe you have added it in the theme but due to some issue with Blogger conditional statement, it is not loading on Post pages

Comment: Without seeing the code as well as the enclosing conditional statements, it is not possible to find the problem. Also, you can try adding the Syntax Highlighter library code into a HTML/JavaScript gadget and it might start working

Comment: The Problem is Solved now...the problem occurred cause the HTTPS redirect was turned on in my Main Blog while it was turned off in the Test Blog...Now the Syntax Highlighter works fine.....Thanks for your help though.